# "Drive already SUBSTed" on deletion of virtual drive in jenkins pipeline on a windows server

Tags: windows, jenkins-groovy, subst

I'm trying to create and use virtual drive in my jenkins pipeline (to avoid the limit of 260 character in windows)

I can create virtual drive using the SUBST command but I cannot delete them which cause problems after the first run... Jenkins is failing on the SUBST command to remove the drive by saying "Drive already SUBSTed".
I really don't understand how he can execute the creation of the virtual drive without any problem but fail to execute the deletion? I'm missing something like an escape character or something else ?

Here is the minimal script causing the problem :

```
node()
{
   stage('Create drive') {
      echo "Already existing virtual drives"
      sh """
      subst
      """
      Character c = 'U'
      echo "Create drive ${c}:"
      sh """
      subst ${c}: .
      """

      echo "Remove drive ${c}:"
      sh """
      subst ${c}: /d
      """
   }
}
```

What I'm getting in the log (after trying with c = J and c = Y before this run):

```
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on **** in E:/Jenkins/workspace/temp_testing_path_lenghty
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Create disk)
[Pipeline] echo
Already existing disks
[Pipeline] sh
+ subst
J:\: => E:\Jenkins\workspace\temp_testing_path_lenghty
Y:\: => E:\Jenkins\workspace\temp_testing_path_lenghty
[Pipeline] echo
Create disks U:
[Pipeline] sh
+ subst U: .
[Pipeline] echo
Remove disks U:
[Pipeline] sh
+ subst U: /d
Drive already SUBSTed
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 1):

I should have used the bat command. The sh command on windows will use the mingw or linux subsytem which doesn't understand option in the form of "/option" but "-option". The correct way is either (preferably the first one):

```
bat """
  subst U: /D
"""
```

or

```
sh """
  subst ${c}: -d
"""
```